# running selenium web tests using cloud load tests in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, selenium, cloud, load-testing, azure-devops

I am trying to add load tests to my selenium web tests using visual studio team services(Visual studio online-vso). I have added chromedriver.exe in the deployment path in the testsettings file. When the tests run I get the error - " System.Invalid.Operations exception: unknown error- cannot find chrome binary" 
Please let me know possible solutions. 
I have also tried this with PhantomJS.exe and followed same steps. It works fine with PhantomJs.exe
Any help would be appriciated. Thanks

Comment: Are you using hosted build agent to run the testing? Or your own build agents or test machine?

Answer (score 0):

I met the issue (System.InvalidOperationException: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary) before and it was caused by the chrome wasn't installed on my test machine. I get it work by installing chrome on it. So you may need to check if chrome is installed successfully on the machine which runs your selenium test.